# routing with model and variable

Tags: laravel

I am trying to test a custom email verification code with route model binding, when 2 wildcards are used, laravel always returns a 404.

this is my route in api.php

```
Route::get('/verify_contact_email/{id}/{hashed_key}', 'CustomEmailVerifyController@verifyContactEmail');
```

this is the controller with verifyContactEmail

```
public function verifyContactEmail(UserContactEmailVerify $id, $hashed_key) { return $id; }
```

when I remove the wildcard {hashed_key} and the $hashed_key, the model shows. I read up on laravel routing documentation, there is no mention of multiple wildcards or passing variable thru URL. Am I doing it wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this: `userContactEmailVerify` a typo? The model name should be PascalCase

Comment: It’s a model declared at the start, for the model binding. Model binding works on just 1 wildcard, but I need to access the variable to check if the hashed key matches for email verification.

Comment: So there is a file called `userContactEmailVerify.php` with the class: `class userContactEmailVerify {`?

Comment: The file is CustomEmailVerifyController.php, with class CustomEmailVerifyController, verifyContactEmail public function. I have edited the error.

Comment: I found out that the wildcards are unable to take hashed strings like $2y$10$EA39Ug.Cs7mltX9/hr.mMuzKRXncHOZyct8h14HHvSDYQtFxa4i1C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the route model binding or controller functions. The problem was discovered that routes do not work with hashing or bcrypt, str_random(20) has replaced the verification code instead of bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
public function verifyContactEmail($id, $hashed_key) { 

   $id = UserContactEmailVerify::findOrFail($id);
   if(isset($id)){
       return $id; 
   }

}
```

Comment: I found out that URL routes does not take hashing very well, so while creating email verification codes, using str_random(20) will do.